# How to add to a collection in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to add an object to an IList entity but the runtime throws a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' exception.

Here is my model:

```
public class Discussion
{
    [Key]
    public int DiscussionId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string UrlTitle { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the problematic line:

```
newDiscussion.Messages.Add(newMessage);
```

Apparently newDiscussion.Messages is null. What am I doing wrong?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize any collections inside of the class's constructor.

```cs
public class Discussion
{
    public Discussion()
    {
        Messages = new List<Message>();
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    // ...
}
```